# What is the benefit of passing Data Transfer Object as parameter to GET in spring boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, resttemplate, dto

I can pass DTO with below two options but can someone explain me which one be better and why  :
1). public List getWithRequestParam(@RequestParam(value = "personDTO") String personDTO)
      throws IOException {public List getWithRequestParam(@RequestParam(value = "personDTO") String personDTO)
      throws IOException {......}

2). public List getWithRequestParam(PersonDTO personDTO){
}

Answer (score 0):

Option 2 is better as this actually provides you with an instance of the PersonDTO object.  Option 1 simply gives you a String, and you'll have to deserialize it yourself to glean anything meaningful from it.

Comment: Thanks Iane, that explains it but how about if I want to pass public List getWithRequestParam(@RequestParam(PersonDTO personDTO) .

Comment: To send it as a request parameter then it will need to be a url-encoded json representation of the PersonDTO.  A better approach, however, would be to send the id of the person as a path variable and look it up in your service layer.

Comment: No my requirement is to send some set of 5 parameters based on which I have to match the DB records, not only the single ID

Comment: In this case I would make each parameter a request parameter, like a=1&b=2&c=3...as you're effectively creating a filter

Comment: Instead of that, I kept all parameters into a DTO and passing into the method